# Vue add class to element without v-model:class?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two elements, that are in two completely different parts of the DOM. And I'm trying to connect the two, so when you hover one element, the other one shows an effect.

**The first element** is in a component and is being displayed with code like this *inside a component*:

```
<button @mouseover="$emit( 'event-hovered', event.id )" @mouseout="$emit( 'event-not-hovered' )">
  Button text    
</button>
```

**The second element** is being generated using code from an [AmCharts-demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/custom-html-elements-map-markers/):

```
createCustomMarker: function (image) {
    var element = document.createElement('button');

    element.className = 'map-marker the-id-' + image.id;
    element.title = image.title;
    element.style.position = 'absolute';
    element.dataset.target = "#id" + image.id;
    element.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');

    image.chart.chartDiv.appendChild(element);

    return element;
}
```

As can be seen, then I've made a `@mouseover` that emits the id back to he main instance. In the main instance, then I have a method that finds the second element. But I do that using regular javascript, since I've had issues rewriting that `createCustomMarker`-function, so both Vue and AmCharts grasps what's going on. But this means that I can't add a class to the second elements (generated by createCustomMarker), the conventional `v-model:class`-way. I tried doing this in a method in the main instance:

```
eventHovered: function( elementId ){
  let markerWithId = document.getElementById( 'id' + elementId );
  markerWithId.classList.add("event-hovered");
  console.log( markerWithId );
}
```

When I console.log the `markerWithId`, then I can see that that has the added class (`event-hovered`). But that doesn't appear on the screen, and I assume that's because Vue is controlling the DOM.

So how do I submit the element back to the DOM? 
And is this a stupid way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the validateNow() function after you edit the class on the marker.
As seen here:
https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCoordinateChart

From the Docs:
This method should be called after you changed one or more properties of any class. The chart will redraw after this method is called.Both attributes, validateData and skipEvents are optional (false by default).

Comment: Whenever I call that, my map-markers disappear (from the DOM as well). :-/